# Is RQDA/RQDAtm package still working?

Tags: r, package, rqda

I'm a newer using `RQDA` package to do some text mining in Chinese.

Downloading and Installing this 2 packages successfully and packages needed to be imported before(such as GTK) are also done.

but when I want to use method `RQDA2tm()`, it always said no such methods.

when I use `?RQDA2tm`, there is no result either.

Is this package still working?

thx.

Comment: Use `RQDA()` to start the programme. if package is installed , It should launch a GUI for you.

Comment: yes. it works. GUI is opening, but what GUI button is this method standing for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found where the problems was.

It was because packages `RQDA` had moved to `RQDAtm`, and corresponding methods had changed names, such as `RQDA2tm()` changed to `codings2tm9()`.